# "This is how I found out the solution" in one word

Tags: single-word-requests

Chances are this is a duplicate, but it's really hard to search for those things:

How do I say: "This is how I arrived at the solution" in one word? I've seen the word used before on Stackoverflow. Someone answered a question and then he followed up with an explanation on how he arrived at the solution. So his answer looked something like

> Answer to the problem
>
> #### Word I'm looking for
>
> I arrived at the solution by first navigating to the `File` menu and then...

The word also has meanings along the lines of "Justification", "Proof of work", "Explanation". I guess "justification" comes closest to it, but that's a word I would rather use in a mathematical proof.

Comment: This is ambiguous. Your question says 'found out', but your example rather refers simply to the procedure of following an already-found solution. Which are you interested in, the term for (often subconscious and intuition-based) process of solution-finding, or for (explicit and step-by-step) description of it? In short, do you use the verb 'arrive' in its mental sense ('arrive at a conclusion') or in its local sense ('arrive at a station')? I suggest 'derivation' and 'description' (of a solution to a problem) respectively; alliterative too.

Comment: Methodology? Sequence? Roadmap?

Comment: @YosefBaskin I thought methodology too, but when I looked up the definition it seemed to be more related to the parameters of working in a given academic discipline.

Comment: Does it *have* to be one word?

Comment: @marcellothearcane Preferrably yes, since I would like to use it as a title to a section of a stackoverflow answer. The term I'm trying to remember definitely consisted of just one word. But other, succinct solutions are welcome too.

Comment: Maybe the word you're looking for is an exclamation, such as ‘Eureka’?

Comment: If you're looking for something short, you could use ["QED"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q.E.D.), which is a well-established abbreviation for Latin "Quad Erat Demonstratum", or in English "Thus is has been demonstrated", and is used at the end of a block of logic to state that with that logic you have proved what you originally set out to prove.

Comment: 'Thusly', ... ;)

Comment: The bottom would be an elaboration of the summary at the top.

Comment: @Simba - Thanks, I just learned something new, my day is complete!

Comment: @KhalidHussain - you beat me to it! My first thought!

Comment: I think he's looking for pretty much the opposite of **TL;DR**.

Comment: @KhalidHussain or "Voilà!" (but since this is *English* Language & Usage... )

Comment: How about "Thought process"?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could go with **[rationale](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rationale)**:

> Definition of rationale
>
> 1 :  an explanation of controlling principles
> of opinion, belief, practice, or phenomena
>
> 2 :  an underlying reason

Comment: Along these lines, "approach" might work.

Answer (score 21):

Personally, I would use:

### [**Reasoning**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reasoning)

> *the drawing of inferences or conclusions through the use of reason.*

Comment: "Reasoning" comes incredibly close to it, but in my opinion it's not entirely suited for situations in which I want to answer a question with something along the lines of: "If you press Ctrl+V, you can paste any text you have previously copied. <This is how I solved your problem>: I read the manual for the program, and on page 56, I found the keyboard shortcut you were looking for!". Doesn't "reasoning" sound a bit odd in this context? Though that may also be because English is not my native language.

Comment: @PawkyPenguin Since you say "... how I *arrived* at ...", I think that neither *rationale* nor *justification* really can be used to describe the process of obtaining the solution, but *reasoning* most certainly can. Rewriting your example a bit: "If you press Ctrl+V, you can paste any text you have previously copied. *Reasoning*: I read the manual, and on page 56, it says: blah blah". With *rationale* or *justification*, the last line would simply be: "*Rationale*: On page 56 of the manual, it says: blah blah."

Comment: @PawkyPenguin based on that context alone the word you're looking for is "source," but that doesn't really fit the definition in the question.

Answer (score 12):

> **Method**
> [meth-uh d]
> /noun
>
> 1. a procedure, technique, or way of doing something, especially in accordance with a definite plan
>
> [Source: Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/method)

Comment: This is just my first thought. I don't think it is quite what you're looking for, but I figured it may be "in the ballpark". I will think on it a bit.

Comment: This comes quite close to it indeed, but I think I'm looking for something less academic.

Comment: Would "methodology" be better suited in this case? Method seems more like a recipe, whereas, "methodology", similar to "rationale" would demonstrate the step by step process of how it was done, and seems more justified... ?

Comment: @Eliseod'Annunzio I thought of methodology too, but when I looked up the definition it seemed to be more related to the parameters of working in a given academic discipline.

Answer (score 8):

You might consider simply using the heading

### Procedure

> **1 a:**  a particular way of accomplishing something or of acting
>
> **2 a:**  a series of steps followed in a regular definite order

- [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/procedure)

*Procedure* is commonly used as a sub-heading when writing a research paper.  For instance, in the field of Psychology, by APA guidelines, the section called "Method" has the following sub-sections:

- Participants
- Materials
- Apparatus
- **Procedure**

For more on this kind of formal "procedure" writing, see the APA guidelines at [Hamilton.edu](https://www.hamilton.edu/academics/centers/writing/writing-resources/how-to-write-an-apa-style-research-paper)

*Procedure* fits especially well with a portion of writing that explicitly goes through the steps required to accomplish something, as exemplified in your sample in the question:

> ...**first** navigating to the File menu and **then**... [etc.]

Comment: I like this answer the most because it has a correlation to a lab report. When you write a lab it contains; Brief, Hypothesis, Procedure, Results, Conclusion. In regards to the OP, the Brief would describe the problem, the proposed solution is the Hypothesis, the method to deduce the solution is the Procedure, the Results confirm the hypothesis in a test case, and the Conclusion summarizes the results.

Answer (score 5):

#### Proof

> evidence or argument establishing or helping to establish a fact or the truth of a statement.

Source: [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/proof)